# Flash Player interface problem

Tags: flex4, freeze, projector, flashplayer-10

I am facing an interface freeze issue with Flash Projector running a flex state based application. A Flash Projector exe was generated from a standalone flash player ver 10.2. The target machine on which the problem occuresd has 10.3.
Basically "screen freeze" means that the user interface is running as usual on Flash Player, but it's not responding to any user input (like button presses). But if we alt-tab to another application, the state changes in the Flash player. There is display with buttons on the screen, but touching the buttons or doing anything else - it did not respond.  Rebooting the computer fixes the problem.
Can you suggest why this is happening? Is there any known bug in Flash Player. 
The problem is this is being hard to reproduce on the developer workstation as it doesn't happen always. But it happens quite often on the target machine running an Intel Atom N270. What debugging steps can you suggest?

Problem : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z25oV9QWRyk

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried publishing the projector in 10.1 or a version of Flash newer than 10.2?  If you are able to publish it as a SWF first, you can use the stand-alone projector exe ([downloadable here](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html)) to load and create a projector from it.

According to [this Adobe bug issue](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-859) (registration required), version 10.1 was supposed to have resolved this, but it sounds like it may have reappeared in 10.2.

Comment: yep, i've tried 10.1. It doesn't support some features of Flex which I am using in the app.

Comment: i've registered another bug report with the latest Adobe Flash Player and Flex 4.5 SDK: https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-31779